# how to check for an element and perform action if it exists

Tags: find, cypress

I have an element with property as this:

`<button class="ed-btn ed-btn-neutral width-100 mb-8">Login using your credentials</button>`

I want to check if this element exists in my page if it does then click on it.

I have tried this:

```
cy.get("body").then($body => {
            if($body.find('.ed-btn ed-btn-neutral width-100 mb-8').length > 0)
            {
                cy.get('.ed-btn ed-btn-neutral width-100 mb-8]').click()
            }
```

but for some reason it does not find this element and click on it though it is present in the page.